# Посимвольный ввод и вывод в Python

Tags: python

Как на Python реализовать ввод одного символа из строки вместо считывания всей строки, как это делает `input()` и, соответственно, печать одного символа в конце текущей строки? т.е. аналоги `getchar()` и `putchar()` в С .

Comment: Вывод; `sys.stdout.write('x')`

Comment: Ввод: можно попробовать `char = sys.stdin.read(1)`

Comment: Посмотрите [пример](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/), мне кажется это то что вам нужно.

Comment: @andy.37 stdin буферизированный, так что это автору вопроса не поможет.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Python read a single character from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/q/510357/4279)

Comment: 1- `getchar()` и `putchar()` работают с байтами, а не символами. 2- вы возможно хотите аналог `getch()` (прочитать ввод с консоли/терминала не дожидаясь Enter), а не `getchar()`. 3- Вывести легко, достаточно `sys.stdout.flush()` вызвать после `print/sys.stdout.write`, чтобы буфер освободить.